# Asp.net and Bootstrap validation‏ at runtime

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there a way to use Bootstrap validation with Asp.net getting the validation rules from a database?

What I mean is, the rules such as required field, field length, date, … are stored in the database and we get these rules at run time.

Thank you for help.